# Android onOptionsItemSelected(...) listener for all activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, handler

I want to write one handler for all activities. But I have one problem: I know that for this task I must inherit Activity class and override this handler like this:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But what I must to do when I heve some activities extended from Activity and other from MapActivity?

Comment: Why not just create a separate class and use it among all your activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible since multiple inheritence in Java isn't possible and `MapActivity` and `Activity` can't extend a class that you control.

You'll have to have an `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method in each of your base activities, but they can share the same code if you call a separate class that's shared.

e.g.

```
class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        MenuHelper.handleOnItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

.

```
class BaseMapActivity extends MapActivity {
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        MenuHelper.handleOnItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

.

```
class MenuHelper {

   public static void handleOnItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          // do something..
   }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I know this, but if in my handler I use some private variable of one of my activity. For ex. when sending Context like someMethod(this) (if declaration: public void someMethod(Context context)) ?

Comment: Yes, you can pass the activity into your handler method if it's required, otherwise just pass the field required directly into the method.

Comment: So don't do that.  Park your variable in shared preferences or subclass Application.

Comment: Ok, for ex. I can pass context of my activity to the method with menuItem, but how can I call startActivityForResult(...) method from method of the MenuHelper class?

Comment: You would have to pass `Activity` or `MapActivity` instead of `Context` into the `MenuHelper` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your MyMapActivity class extending MapActivity, and in your `onOptionsItemSelected` implementation for this and the other `MyActivity`, call the same procedure.

Or you can set a custom listener for every menu item with [`MenuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setOnMenuItemClickListener%28android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener%29), and make this listener dispatch events to your procedure.